# Implement a html-widget (form) into an asp-site

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, forms, widget

I try to implement the following widget in my asp.net-site:

```
<div style="width: 175px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: right; background-color:#FFFFFF;">
<img src="http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/img/igm-sbblogo.gif" width="110" height="18" alt="SBB|CFF|FFS" />
<h1 style="width:175px; background-color: #DDDDDD; color: #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; padding: 2px 0px; margin: 0; height: 15px; text-align: left;clear:both;"> Fahrplan</h1>
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: #F8F8F8; margin: 0; padding: 0px;" summary="Layout">
<form action="http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/query.exe/dn?externalCall=yes&DCSext.wt_fp_request=partner_mini" name="formular" method="post" style="display:inline" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="queryPageDisplayed" value="yes">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="width: 170px; margin: 2px;" class="ig">
<tr>
<th nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; font-weight:bold; width: 55px;">
 Von: 
</th>
<td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:2px 3px 2px 0px;" colspan="2">
<input type="hidden" name="REQ0JourneyStopsSID" value="A=1@O=Stettbach, Bahnhof@X=8596132@Y=47397270@U=85@L=008591065@B=1@p=1338878028@">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Stettbach, Bahnhof</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:2px 3px 2px 0px;">
<select name="REQ0JourneyStopsZA" style="background-color:#fff; border: 1px solid #7F9DB9; color: #000; width: 60px; font-size:11px; margin:0px 0px;">
<option selected="selected" value="7">Nach:</option>
<option  value="1">Bhf./Haltest.</option>
<option  value="2">Ort, Strasse Nr.</option>
<option  value="4">Sehenswürdigkeit</option>
</select>
</td>
<td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:2px 3px 2px 0px;" colspan="2">
<input type="text" name="REQ0JourneyStopsZG" value="" size="16" style="background-color:#fff; border: 1px solid #7F9DB9; color: #000; width: 100px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px" accesskey="t" tabindex="2">
<input type="hidden" name="REQ0JourneyStopsZID">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; font-weight:bold; width: 55px;">
 Datum: 
</th>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:2px 3px 2px 0px;">
<b>08.06.12</b>
<input type="hidden" name="REQ0JourneyDate" value="08.06.12" accesskey="d">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; font-weight:bold; width: 55px;">
 Zeit: 
</th>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:2px 3px 2px 0px;">
<input type="text" name="REQ0JourneyTime" value="11:02" size="5" maxlength="5" style="background-color:#fff; border: 1px solid #7F9DB9; color: #000; width: 100px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px" accesskey="c" tabindex="4">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th> </th>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:2px 3px 2px 0px;">
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="REQ0HafasSearchForw" value="1"  checked style="margin-right:3px;">Abfahrt 
<br /><input class="radio" type="radio" name="REQ0HafasSearchForw" value="0"   style="margin-right:3px;">Ankunft
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">
<input type="hidden" name="start" value="Suchen">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="Verbindung suchen" tabindex="5" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:center; width:130px; vertical-align: middle; cursor:pointer; -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; background-color:#EE0000; border:1px solid #B20000; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; height:auto; line-height:20px; padding:0px 10px; text-decoration:none; white-space:nowrap;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">
<a style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:left; margin-top:4px; color: #6B7786; text-decoration:none; display:block;" href="http://www.sbb.ch/166" target="_blank" title="Aktuelle Informationen zu Streiks und grösseren Unterbrüchen im Schienenverkehr."><img src="http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/img/one/icon_arrow_right.png" alt="" style="vertical-align:top; padding-right:2px; border:none;" />Bahnverkehrsinformation</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var time=new Date();
var hour = time.getHours(); hour=(hour<10)? '0'+hour:hour;
var minute = time.getMinutes();minute=(minute<10)? '0'+minute:minute;
var travelTime = hour+':'+minute;
document.formular.REQ0JourneyTime.value=travelTime;
// /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Source of the code: http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/help.exe/en?application=INPUTGEN&tpl=inputgen_start

When I create a normal HTML-site the widget works without problems.

But in an asp-site there is a problem with the javascript.
In the line "document.formular.REQ0JourneyTime.value=travelTime;" there comes this error-message:

"JScript runtime error: The property "REQ0JourneyTime" can not be retrieved value: The object is null or undefined."

I think the problem has something to do with the form-tag of the widget ands the post-action, but I doent know, what exactly it is :S

Does somebody know how to fix that issue? Thank you very much!

Michael

Comment: Can we see some of the code that this is embedded in? Since it only fails in the asp.net site, that appears to be causing the problem, so we should look at that code.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be accessing the form by `document.forms.formular` or `document.forms['formular']`, not `document.formular`.

Also, on the end of the `<input ... name="REQ0JourneyTime" ... />` you have `>` not `/>`.

Comment: ok, thank you. But unfortunately that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer. You left off the self closing tag of that input. That should fix the problem, depending on your browser.

Comment: I have now closed all input tags with "/>" and change the document.formular to "document.forms.formular.REQ0JourneyTime.value=travelTime;" but the error rest the same. Is there not an problem with the second form-tag?

Comment: Also, you have a lot more <input> tags without the /> on the end. I don't know if that'll work, but you should try fixing them anyway.

Comment: yes, I have all tags correctly closed. The code is not from me, its from the linked site in the question. But in a only html-site it works without problem. The problem has something to do with the asp.net technology

Comment: Can we see some of the code that this is embedded in? Since it only fails in the asp.net site, that appears to be causing the problem, so we should look at that code. -- As posted on the comments to your question. (You have just said it is the asp.net, can we see that code please?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have nested an HTML form inside your ASPX server-side form tag.

[Form tag on ASP.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926481/form-tag-on-asp-net-page)

You could  try using AJaX within your widget rather than posting back via traditions form.

Read this article too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164151.aspx

Comment: I was gonna say... One form per page?

Comment: One *server-side* form per page.

Comment: Yes. That is understandable (still frustrating), also your two links are the same.